# Creating an accordion-style submenu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create an accordion style menu, similar to [this demonstration available from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol).  However, i'd like a few things changed.

On my accordion menu, if one of the menu options is already expanded (part of the "active" CSS class in the example above) and the user clicks on another menu item, the currently expanded menu should collapse prior to the expansion of the item that was just clicked on.

Can anyone offer me some help to achieve this?  Thanks

Comment: Please share the code of what you tired so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the javascript code to this

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var clicked = this;
    [].slice.apply(acc).forEach(function(item, index){
      var panel = item.nextElementSibling,
          clicked_index = [].slice.apply(acc).indexOf(clicked);
      if (index !== clicked_index) {
       item.classList.remove("active");
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      }     
    });    
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Sorry I missed that, check this out. I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Seems good.  Here's the next part:  I'd like to be able to collapse an expanded item by clicking on it as well.

Comment: Check the solution now.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much!